# Fancybox 3 thumb source

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

If I open group of image in this format, fancybox will use img for thumbnail, and href for large image source.

```
<a href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8148/29324593462_abebaddc38_k.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8148/29324593462_f890687b7a_m.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5499/30972532232_051e1dc57e_h.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5499/30972532232_e9a298a0c5_m.jpg" />
</a>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/WjVXyx?editors=1000

However, if I open fancybox using api like os:

```
$.fancybox.open([
{
    src  : '1_b.jpg',
    opts : {
        caption : 'First caption'
    }
},
{
    src  : '2_b.jpg',
    opts : {
        caption : 'Second caption'
    }
    }
]);
```

Fancybox will use src for both thumb and large image.

Example: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/GEKgjp?editors=1010

Is there a way to specify thumb source in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass source using `thumb` option:

```
opts : {
    caption : 'First caption',
    thumb   : 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8148/29324593462_f890687b7a_m.jpg'
}
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGboRW?editors=1010